# Parameter converted from null to DateTime.MinValue when called using Invoke in C# 2.0

Tags: c#, reflection

I have code a bit like this

```
public class MyObject
{
    private bool IsValidDay(ref DateTime theDate)
    {

    ...
    }
}


MethodInfo[] methods = myObjectInstance.GetType().GetMethod("IsValidDay", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
object[] args = { null };
bool val = (bool)method.Invoke(myObjectInstance, args);
```

But when the method is called, from within the IsValidDay method, theDate is DateTime.MinValue. This seems awfully weird - I'd perhaps expect a NullReferenceException to be thrown but not an automatic conversion.

In case you are wondering, this is code in a unit test. (in use the method is typically called via a public method that takes object).

As far as some other code which is subsequently called is concerned, DateTime.MinValue and null are not the same thing, so it's a little bit of a problem.

Any clues?? Suggestions.

Comment: What do you want it to do then?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In the end, in this case, I think I'll go with the notion that the method doesn't actually need to be tested vs null, and note to myself that invoking methods via reflection doesn't always throw an exception when a straight function call would.

Other people may find the nullable type suggestion useful (though I imagine everybody has conttoned onto these by now...)

Answer (score 3):

A DateTime variable can't be null.  It's not a reference type, so there won't be a null reference exception.

You could do:

```
private bool IsValidDay(ref DateTime? theDate)
{
   if(theDate.HasValue)...
}
```

Here's a link talking about nullable types:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1t3y8s4s%28VS.80%29.aspx

I think I get what you are asking.... in the case of your code (especially because of the ref parameter, you can't have variance on a parameter with ref or out).  It has to pass in a DateTime object.  It can't be anything else.....so the null argument has to be converted to something to get the function to work.

Comment: I know about nullable types, have used them in the past, and agree they are probably the tool for this job - unfortunately, I am maintaining /extending existing code which I can't change to a nullable type.

Answer (score 3):

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a89hcwhh.aspx):

> Any object in this array that is not explicitly initialized with a value will contain the default value for that object type. For reference-type elements, this value is null. **For value-type elements, this value is 0, 0.0, or false, depending on the specific element type.**

The default value of `DateTime` is `DateTime.MinValue`:

```
DateTime.MinValue == new DateTime() // true
```

---

This explains why `DateTime.MinValue` gets passed to the method when you call it with `null`.

Note that you cannot pass `null` to the method anyway when you call it without reflection:

```
DateTime dt = null; // cannot assign null to value type
obj.IsValidDay(ref dt);
```

**So I'd say you don't need to test your method with a null reference.**

---

If you want your method to accept `null`, you can change the declaration to `DateTime?` as others have already pointed out:

```
private bool IsValidDay(ref DateTime? dt) { ... }
```

Comment: For the nullable type suggestion see my comment above. In the calling unit test code the value is explicitly initialised to null - but it acting as you describe above nonetheless. I wll have to check the the actual production code - I thought the method may be called via reflection, but I am not sure - hill have to dig through our framework code to make sure it doesn't.

Answer (score 2):

`DateTime` has a value, I suggest you use `DateTime?` (or `Nullable<DataTime>`) to support nulls

Answer (score 1):

Invoke() method takes an array of values for the target method parameters. According to MSDN, uninitialized elements of this array corresponding to the **ref** parameters will be initialized with the default value (in this case **DateTime.MinValue**) before the target method call.

Also, the value in the parameters array corresponding to the **ref** parameter will be updated after the target method call.

In your case you shouldn't test the method with a **null** value because it's not a valid value for the **DateTime** data type.

This is a comment from Invoke method doc in MSDN library:

"If the method or constructor represented by this instance takes a ref parameter, no special attribute is required for that parameter in order to invoke the method or constructor using this function. **Any object in this array that is not explicitly initialized with a value will contain the default value for that object type.** For reference-type elements, this value is null. **For value-type elements, this value is 0, 0.0, or false, depending on the specific element type.**"

Also found this tutorial:
[Passing "ref" Parameters](http://csharpfeeds.com/post/1724/Csharp_Reflection_Part_5.aspx)

Comment: as far as I know the only way to pass a ref parameter to Invoke is as I have done in my example code, which I came up with from the MSDN entry on ref parameters.

Comment: Yep, it appears I didn't understand Invoke() call with ref parameters correctly. Fixing my response...

Answer (score 0):

Only [reference types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/490f96s2.aspx) can be null.  [DateTime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime%28VS.100%29.aspx) (like int, bool, structs, and enums) is a [Value Type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s1ax56ch.aspx). Therefore DateTime cannot be null, just like an enum can't be null.  You can use the [Nullable generic](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1t3y8s4s%28VS.80%29.aspx), by declaring it as `DateTime?`.  This will allow you to check it for null.